# Find the tensions in the supporting ropes of an inclined heavy beam supported by two diferent kinds of ropes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, elasticity, statics, non-linear-systems

Recently I was making some late-revisit (for self reference) to undergraduate physics topics from the book **Ohanian's Physics**, 2E expanded-1989, which I loved to use during my freshman undergraduate engineering physics education... Later in my sophomore, I've even taken a **statics** course from ME too, yet as far as I can remember (two decades ago!) that course didn't include **elasticity** ; i.e., all bodies were **rigid**, during analysis of forces. Anyway, here is a problem of deformed-statics including young's modulus, that I cannot reach an *analytical solution* (it's not supposed to be a difficult problem, and that's the confusing part actually). Very probably, I'm just missing critical approximation, a simplification assumption, that's why the exact equations tend to be impossible to solve analytically.

Below shows the problem 59, from chapter 14:

[image]

I preparred this figure as a guide for solution:

[image]

Young's modulus for nylon-rope is Yn = 3.6 GPa, and for steel-rope is Ys = 200 GPa. The problem asks for the angle $\alpha$ that the beam makes with the horizontal. My solution attempt begins with writing the equations of statics on the beam, but that's all. Despite all of my algebraic-trigonometric attempts, I could not find a **simple** looking yet fully-analytic solution for the angle $\alpha$. At this point, an approximation such as $\alpha \ll 1$ could be useful, but I don't want to sacrifice the generality of the problem, and instead look for a general solution including larger angles as well.

- 1-) Fx = 0 : $T_{1f} \cos(\theta+\alpha) - T_{2f} \cos(\phi-\alpha) = 0$
- 2-) Fy = 0 : $T_{1f} \sin(\theta+\alpha) + T_{2f} \sin(\phi-\alpha) = W$
- 3-) $\tau_1 = 0$ : $T_{2f} \sin(\theta) = 0.5 W \cos(\alpha)$
- 4-) $\tau_2 = 0$ : $T_{1f} \sin(\phi) = 0.5 W \cos(\alpha)$

and a fifth equation comes from the final *triangle* geometry (cosine law):

- 5-) $L_b^2 = L_{nf}^2 + L_{sf}^2 + 2 L_{nf} L_{sf} \cos(\theta+\phi) $

where the final lengths of nylon and steel ropes are found from their final equilibrium stresses, T1f and T2f, based on Young's elasticity as:

$$ L_{nf} = L_n ~(1 + \frac{T_1}{Y_n A_n} ) $$
and
$$L_{sf} = L_s ~(1 + \frac{T_2}{Y_s A_s} ) $$

where cross-sectional areas of the ropes are $A_n = \pi R_n^2$ and $A_s = \pi R_s^2$, as given in th prblem statement...

After writing these five equations, there does not seem an analytic solution for the angle $\alpha$? Any ideas? I've tried to use Matlab's symbolic solver but, either I've done something wrong or it takes excessively long, so that I've just aborted the process...

*NOTE*: to my understanding, exact solution of this problem is difficult in the sense that, to find the tensions in the rope, one needs the rope angles, but to find those rope angles, one needs the rope lengths, but to find the rope lengths, one needs the rope tensions, so in a cyclic manner, an exact analytic solution seems not possible(?), unless some simplifying assumptions are made. So this problem assumes some simplifications of which I cannot find.

Comment: @BobD Hi! Do you have some ideas or opinions here? Eventhough It's more like a math problem at current level, it's still reasonable to include here, isn't it? Any helps appreciated. PLease feel free to ask for any clarifications.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you're supposed to assume that $\alpha \ll 1$.  Even if the entire weight of the beam was applied to one or the other cable individually, the stress in each one would still be much less than its Young's modulus (about 4% for the nylon & 1% for the steel.)  This would seem to indicate that neither cable stretches by a significant fraction of its own length, and so the beam will still be nearly horizontal.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Hi thank you! Yes very probably the expected solution hinges on a small angle assumption for $\alpha$, yet I would still look for an exact analytical solution for the angle $\alpha$ in a general setting where the fractional changes in the rope lengths can be large as well as small... Do you have any suggestions to solve the set of equations? The physics of te process does not seem to permit a solution? Can this problem indeed be solved? Or may be they are just unsolveable, like most other nonlinear algebraic equations. And do you have any idea why this question was closed?

Comment: I doubt that the full non-linear equations are exactly soluble;  there are many problems in physics that can't be solved analytically (though they don't usually come up in introductory classes.)  This doesn't mean there isn't a "solution" — if you built the thing to a high precision, you could actually measure $\alpha$, and that would be the solution — it's just that it can't be expressed in a "nice" form.

Comment: As far as why the question was closed, questions that focus on the details of a specific problem are generally off-topic here unless they focus on a specific physics concept;  and many users tend to vote to close anything that has the least whiff of "do my homework for me".  So it's hard to ask a question like yours on this site without it being closed.